# How do I post a form, update a query and display the results on the same page with ColdFusion/jQuery?

Tags: jquery, sql, ajax, forms, coldfusion

**Objective:**

I have a large form with a dynamically created size (it's a product order form, input type="number").  After filling out the form, the user clicks the "Place Order" button, and I want to display a summary order in a lightbox (on the same page) so they can confirm.

**Currently Used Method:**

1) I have the form post to an invisible iframe on the page.

```
<cfform id="refSubmit" action="/createTable.cfm" method="post" target="hiddenFrame">
```

2) createTable.cfm loops through the form fields submitted and creates a temporary table in SQL Server.  This section is working perfectly.

3) I'm using jquery .submit() to wait for the success of the submission of the form, turning on the lightbox and using .load() on a page to display the confirmation.

```
$("input[name*='submit']").click(function(event) {
  var submitButton = $(this);
    // If lightbox is open, then close it.
    if ($("#confirmationLightbox").is(":visible")){
      $("#confirmationLightbox").toggle().children().remove();
      event.preventDefault();
    } else {
      $("#refSubmit").submit();
      $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "createTable.cfm",
        success: function() {
          // Changing the delay does resolve the issue, but not properly
          $("#changeIconLightbox").toggle().delay(0).queue(function(){
            $(this).load('/includes/inc_lightboxes/orderConfirmation.cfm');
          });
        }
      });
    }
  });
```

**Problem:**

Although the table created from createTable.cfm IS being built correctly 100% of the time, when the query is called in orderConfirmation.cfm, it's calling that query before it's finished building.  So what's being outputted isn't waiting for the table to finish being created.

I know my ajax POST is doing exactly as it should be.  It's triggering the success line because although the form data has been successfully sent, the cfm file hasn't finished processing.

**Question:**

SO, the reason I'm here.  How do I make sure that the .load() line waits to execute until after createTable.cfm has finished it's server side processing?  As you can see, I did attempt to use a .delay().  I can of course, pop in a number, and make the user wait for the process, but that means someone ordering 1 item is going to wait the same time as someone ordering 2000 unique items.

Because this was asked, here is the code I'm using to create the unique table.

```
<!--- Create Unique ID for Table --->
  <cfset SESSION.tempOrder = Replace(CreateUUID(),"-","","All")>

  <!--- Create Temp Order Table --->
  <cfquery name="qCreateTempOrder" datasource="#REQUEST.dsn#" username="#REQUEST.dsu#" password="#REQUEST.dsp#">
    CREATE TABLE order_temp_#SESSION.tempOrder#
    ( id INTEGER IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
    productId INTEGER NOT null,
    quantity INTEGER NOT null
    );
  </cfquery>
```

Comment: Why are you both posting to a hidden iframe and posting via an AJAX call (to the same page)? In this manner, it's hard to have each separate request rely on the other. Could you eliminate the iframe, instead collect and post the parameters only in the AJAX, so that `success` is really only invoked once the processing is completed?

Comment: That's actually where I started.  I realize my ajax call probably isn't right.  But originally what I had was the cfm file that created the table was also the one I performed the .load() on.  The problem I was having was I wasn't able to stop the form post from taking me away from that page AND sending the information.  The iframe really does feel like a macgyver type solution.  If there is a way to accomplish what you suggest, that would surely be the more ideal method.

Comment: Your approach with creating and populating a temporary table using cfquery is risky.  In addition to the problems you are encountering, you run the risk of having User B interfering with User A.  I suggest transferring all that code to a stored procedure.

Comment: The user A and B conflict is already solved on the ColdFusion side.  A session variable is created with a unique name, and the temporary table is named using that variable.  With that being said, it will ultimately be done within a stored procedure once I know the ajax is working.

Comment: I'm currently using MS SQL.  Not sure how to post code in the comment here, so I've added it as an edit to my original post.

Comment: Given the way that sql server treats temporary tables, in a stored procedure, you can use the same name every time.  That's one less thing to worry about.

Comment: Completely agree with that.  But I have multiple uses for also having that session variable later.

I am however, still stuck on how to solve my original problem.  I'm considerably stronger with ColdFusion than I am with jQuery at this point.  Do you have any suggestions on that by chance?

Comment: I tend to approach things differently.  I would do things in the following order.  First, write the stored procedure.  Then, write a function in a cfc file that calls it.  Finally, I would do the jquery stuff.

Comment: Sounds like you might need to put some additional logic in your `orderConfirmation.cfm` template to check that the other process `createTable.cfm` has completed before returning. Of course then your users are waiting. So maybe send back a _still processing_ message and give the user a _check again_ button to re-request the `orderConfirmation.cfm` template. **OR** Modify the `createTable.cfm` template to only return after the tables are created. How is it returning before the tables are complete???

Comment: And get rid of that `cfform` call. You should not need that. In fact it may be interfering. When you use those `cf...` tags javascript gets embedded in the response that may be interfering with your jQuery/javascript.

Comment: *wasn't able to stop the form post from taking me away from that page AND sending the information* Maybe I am missing something but it sounds like that is the problem you should be trying to resolve, rather than implementing a somewhat convoluted workaround.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm going to post what ended up working in the event someone else comes to this page, and also to show my problem has been resolved.

As suggested by Miguel-F, I stripped out the cf on the form.

```
<form id="refSubmit">
```

And my jQuery now looks like this.

```
$("#refSubmit").submit(sendForm);
  var confirmLightbox = $("#confirmationLightbox");
  var placeOrder = $("input[name*='submit']");

  function sendForm(event) {
    if (confirmLightbox.is(":visible")){
      confirmLightbox.toggle().children().remove();
      placeOrder.val("Place Order");
      event.preventDefault();
    } else {
      $('<input name="processing" style="margin: 5px 10px; float: right;" type="button" class="processingButton" value="Processing..." disabled>').insertBefore(placeOrder.hide());
      $.post('process/createTable.cfm',$("#refSubmit").serialize(),function(){
        confirmLightbox.toggle().delay(0).queue(function(){
        $(this).load('/includes/inc_lightboxes/jcorderconfirmation.cfm', function(){
          var confirmOrder = $("button[name*='confirm']");
          placeOrder.show().val("Edit Order");
          $("input.processingButton").remove();
          $("input[name*='confirmOrder']").on("click", function(){
            if($(this).is(':checked')){
              confirmOrder.removeAttr("disabled");
            } else {
              confirmOrder.prop("disabled", true);
            }
          });
          $("button[name*='cancel']").on("click", function(){
            confirmLightbox.toggle().children().remove();
            placeOrder.val("Place Order");
          });
          confirmOrder.on("click", function(){
          alert("Products successfully added to inventory.");
        });
      });
    });
  });
}
return false;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for coming back and posting your solution. It would be helpful if you included some detail around what made this work. Did you have to modify your ColdFusion templates at all (aside from removing the cfform) or was it all JavaScript code? Glad you got it working.

Comment: It was a combination of two parts.  First off, having an action on the cfform was of course trying to redirect the page, and that's why I ended up using that iframe.  So I was trying to send the form twice, once in the tag, and again with the jquery.  Instead, removing the action and letting jquery send the information did exactly as I needed.  You'll also see I modified the jquery and used a callback in the $.post line.  This allowed for the processing to finish.  Since this was posted, I've modified the createTable.cfm to be a cfc file, and it's calling a stored proc in SQL.  Hope that helps